# Vue emit ref of another element on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ref

Hello how i can get the element by className or something else. So i need to get element by className actually but i can't figure out how to do that in this case:

here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cihanzengin/aq9Laaew/294154/
Simply i wanna do that: When click to menu in method i try to get element which have classname nav. I tried to make with ref but i can't

here is my code :

```
<div id="app">
        <some-component  @get-element="getElement"></some-component>
    </div>

    <script>
        var someComponent = Vue.component("some-component", {
        template: `
            <div class="columns mobile-navigation">
            <div class="column drawer">
                <a class="is" @click="$emit('get-element')">MENU</a>
            </div>
            <div ref="nav" class="column mobile-nav-wrapper">
                <p> Some Text </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        `
        });

        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {

        },
        components: {
            "mobile-nav": mobileNav
        },
        methods: {
            getElement() {
            console.log(this.$refs.nav);
            }
        }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the `get-element` event?

Comment: sorry i edited. its just click event method name

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
var classToCheck = 'myclass';

if( this.$refs.nav.classList.includes(classToCheck) ){
 // includes above class
}
```

OR

```
myclickevent(event){

    event.target.classList // this will get you classList of of clicked element then you can compare

}
```

This contains all the classes for your element

```
this.$refs.nav.classList
```

Comment: here is error. I tried. I can't access to ref actually. Maybe its working in another way when u work in not .vue template like me

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution:

here is need to add `**<some-component>**` to ref attribute for accessing to ref inside jsx.

Then will possible to access to nav ref with: `this.$refs.someRef.$refs.nav`

```
<div id="app">
        <some-component  @get-element="getElement" ref="someRef"></some-component>
    </div>

    <script>
        var someComponent = Vue.component("some-component", {
        template: `
            <div class="columns mobile-navigation">
            <div class="column drawer">
                <a class="is" @click="$emit('get-element')">MENU</a>
            </div>
            <div ref="nav" class="column mobile-nav-wrapper">
                <p> Some Text </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        `
        });

        var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {

        },
        components: {
            "mobile-nav": mobileNav
        },
        methods: {
            getElement() {
            console.log(this.$refs.someRef.$refs.nav);
            }
        }
        });
    </script>
```